# How to remove borders in Activity android

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, border

I can't understand what a reason of these borders in my Activity.

[image]

Could you help me to remove it please?

I have found out advice to replace match_parent with fill_parent, but it doesn't help of course.

I have marked red only places in which you can see the problem, but it seems that there are borders fill all height of screen at left and right.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:context="AppName.NewNoteActivity">

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/newNoteScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/newNoteVideoView"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/inputName"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />

        <TimePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inputDate"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickInputDate"
            android:text="@string/activity_new_note_helloText_inputDate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Save"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you removed the padding from the activity?

Comment: have you tried to enable the "Show Layout Bounds" in the developer settings? Maybe the parent is filled, but the Button has this small transparent borders

Comment: SuperThomasLab, but it doesn't have padding. What do you mean?

Comment: Wicked161089, I will try now.

Comment: Your xml layout looks fine on mine. As a comment on `match_parent` and `fill_parent`, they are the **same thing**. `match_parent` is the new used name. They both return the same thing.

Comment: I have added picture with layout bounds.

Comment: I tried to set android:padding="0dp" to all containers, but it doesn't help. So I don't know what to do with it :(